# Button not being disabled on keyevent of textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I was trying to print error message in front of a textbox using following code :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <%int n=(Integer)request.getAttribute("n");%>

        $(document).ready(function(){

        var A=<%=n%>;
        $('input[name^=txtDynamic_]').keyup(function () {
        if ($(this).val() > A) {
            //alert("inside if");
            $(this).next().html('Greater than Total shares');
            $("#flagvalue").val("invalid"); 
        }
        else{
            $(this).next().html('');
            $("#flagvalue").val("valid"); 
        }
        });

        if($("#flagvalue").val()=="invalid")
        {
            $("#submitbutton").prop('disabled', true);
        }
        else{
            $("#submitbutton").prop('disabled', false);
        }
        });


</script>
```

and the form is :

```
    <FORM METHOD=POST ACTION="stegnographyonshares" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 

        <c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="${myK}">
        Enter The  ${i} share number: <input type="textbox" name="txtDynamic_${i}"/><span></span>

        <br />
        <br>
        </br>
    </c:forEach> 
        <br></br>
        <INPUT TYPE="file" NAME="file" value="file"> 
        <br></br>

       <input type="submit" value="SAVE" id="submitbutton">
        <input type="hidden" id="flagvalue"/>
    </form>
```

Whats problem in this ? the script code is not running and though printing the error message but not disabling the button.Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var A = <%=(Integer)request.getAttribute("n")%>       
        $('input[name^=txtDynamic_]').keyup(function () {
        if ($(this).val() > A) {
            $(this).next().html('Greater than Total shares');
            flag=1;
        }
        else{
                $(this).next().html('');
        }
        });
});
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/UMLe2/

**Update:**

http://jsfiddle.net/UMLe2/2/

Comment: What change you had made ?

Comment: @user3509463, if (+this.value > A) changed to if ($(this).val() > A)

Comment: @user3509463 have you checked printing the value of `n` ?

Comment: @sankrish Yeah ,its right,But its not going in keyup function.Alert outside it prints the value of n,but alert inside keyup does not work

Comment: @user3509463, I have added one demo in my answer. Please Check. I think issue with your 'n' value.

Comment: @RGS Is the form correct?Means does the enctype of form affects the result?

Comment: @RGS Also i included <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script> at top of the jsp page.Is their any other import that i require?

Comment: @user3509463, Warp your code inside dom ready function. I have updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: @user3509463, Use latest jquery version.

Comment: @RGS    
 
I require to disable a button too.Please help .I edited my post

Comment: @user3509463, I have added another demo for button disable action in my answer. Please check.

Comment: @RGS I edited my code but the problem is same.The button is not disabled though the message apperas beside the textbox.What can be the reason please check

Comment: @user3509463, Use latest script. http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js. Because 'prop' supported only in higher version of jquery.

Answer (score 0):

call your code when DOM structure ready, Because the code you have written load prior to the DOM structure generation

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//Put your js code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

<%int n=(Integer)request.getAttribute("n");%>
    var A=<%=n%>;
    $('input[name^=txtDynamic_]').keyup(function () {
    if ($(this).val() > A) {
        $(this).next().html('Greater than Total shares');
        flag=1;
    }
    else{
            $(this).next().html('');
    }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: the code runs fine if i put A=some value in if ($(this).val() > A) .BUt when again replace it it again doesnt run.

Comment: I require to disable a button too.Please help .I edited my post